# Are mass and angular momentum related at a quantum level?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, mass, angular-momentum

Is the mass of an atom related to the amount of angular momentum it contains?

It makes sense to me that since the waveform of an electron is much much larger than a particle in the nucleus that its relative angular momentum would be much less and thus its mass would be much less.

Comment: I narrowed the question down to the fundamental question of how mass and energy relate in its various forms. The angular momentum I imagine is the sum of the waveforms contained in the atom.

Comment: Are you talking about the spin angular momentum, or the orbital angular momentum in an atom?

Answer (score 1):

> Is the mass of an atom related to the amount of angular momentum it contains?

Not really. It is slightly related in the sense that the amount of angular momentum affects the amount of energy it has, and this has a slight effect on the mass due to Einstein's $E=mc^2$, but that's it. In particular, it's important to stress that the angular kinetic energy associated with the angular momentum contributes equally to $E$ (and hence to $mc^2$) as do the radial kinetic energy and the potential energy due to the electrostatic interactions between the electrons and the nucleus.

This means that adding some angular momentum can both raise as well as lower the total energy. Oxygen, for example, [has total angular momentum $J=\sqrt{2(2+1)}\hbar=\sqrt{6}\hbar$ in its ground state](http://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/Handbook/Tables/oxygentable5.htm), and lowering its angular momentum takes at the very least $19\:\mathrm{meV}$.

That said, the resulting increases in mass are absolutely tiny. The energy ranges are in the order of one electronvolt, whereas the lightest atom, hydrogen, has a mass of about $940\:\mathrm{MeV}/c^2$, some eight orders of magnitude bigger.

Finally,

> It makes sense to me that since the waveform of an electron is much much larger than a particle in the nucleus that its relative angular momentum would be much less and thus its mass would be much less.

fails to make any sense to me.

Comment: See page 174 of [A Zeptospace Odyssey](http://i.stack.imgur.com/c13hg.jpg) where CERN physicist Gian Guidice says 98% of proton mass results from E=mc², whilst electromagnetic effects and the Higgs mechanism account for 1% each. Also see articles about proton spin such as [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_spin_crisis).

Comment: @John Indeed, a large fraction of the proton and neutron mass comes from kinetic-energy effects. I don't see a particular relevance to the question as posed, though, within the limits of its very vague formulation.

Comment: You would if looked again at the OP and considered electron spin angular momentum, then proton spin angular momentum, and then moved on to the hydrogen atom and the electron's orbital angular momentum. Your answer concerns orbital angular momentum only. _Unwary beginner_ indeed.

Answer (score -2):

> Are mass and angular momentum related at a quantum level?

Yes, most definitely, because of the wave nature of matter. You can appreciate this by thinking in terms of light in a box. If you catch a massless photon in a gedanken mirror-box, the mass of the box is increased. When you open the box, it's a radiating body that loses mass. That might not sound much like angular momentum, but when you get the light going round and round the box rather than back and forth, you start to get an idea of angular momentum rather than linear momentum:

[image]

Have a read of [Light is Heavy](http://www.tardyon.de/mirror/hooft/hooft.htm) by van der Mark and (not the Nobel) 't Hooft for more. The photon is still moving at c, but overall it isn't moving at c with respect to you, so it's effectively at rest. It still exhibits resistance to change-in-motion, but we don't call it energy E=hf or momentum p=hf/c. We divide by c again and say E=mc², and we call it mass.

Also check out the [Einstein-de Haas effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93de_Haas_effect) which *"demonstrates that spin angular momentum is indeed of the same nature as the angular momentum of rotating bodies as conceived in classical mechanics"*. And of course see [electron magnetic moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_magnetic_moment#Magnetic_moment_of_an_electron), and don't forget [electron diffraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_diffraction), or that that in [atomic orbitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital#Electron_properties) electrons exist as standing waves. Note how Einstein referred to an electron on the same line as body in his E=mc² paper?

*"The kinetic energy of the body with respect to ($\xi,\eta,\zeta$) diminishes as a result of the emission of light, and the amount of diminution is independent of the properties of the body. Moreover, the difference K0 − K1, like the kinetic energy of the electron (§ 10), depends on the velocity."*

The electron is akin to a photon in a box of its own making. Ditto for the positron. Annihilation is like opening one box with another, then each is a radiating body that loses mass. All of it.

> Is the mass of an atom related to the amount of angular momentum it contains?

Yes. Think of photon energy-momentum as resistance to change-in-motion for a wave propagating linearly at c. Think of electron mass as resistance to change-in-motion for a wave going round and round at c.

> It makes sense to me that since the waveform of an electron is much much larger than a particle in the nucleus that its relative angular momentum would be much less and thus its mass would be much less.

Agreed, the smaller the wavelength the greater the energy / momentum / mass.